# How to bin a pytorch tensor into an array of values

Tags: python, pytorch

Say I have an array of values `w = [w1, w2, w3, ...., wn]` and this array is sorted in ascending order, all values being equally spaced.

I have a pytorch tensor of any arbitrary shape. For the sake of this example, lets say that tensor is:

```
import torch 

a = torch.rand(2,4)
```

assuming `w1=torch.min(a)` and `wn=torch.max(a)`, I want to create two separate tensors, `amax` and `amin`, both of shape `(2,4)` such that `amax` contains values from `w` that are the nearest maximum value to the elements of `a`, and vice-versa for `amin`.

As an example, say:

```
a = tensor([[0.7192, 0.6264, 0.5180, 0.8836],
            [0.1067, 0.1216, 0.6250, 0.7356]])

w = [0.0, 0.33, 0.66, 1]
```

therefore, I would like `amax` and `amin` to be,

```
amax = tensor([[1.000, 0.66, 0.66, 1.000],
               [0.33, 0.33, 0.66, 1.00]])

amin = tensor([[0.66, 0.33, 0.33, 0.66],
               [0.00, 0.00, 0.33, 0.66]])
```

What is the fastest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could compute for all points in `a`, the difference with each bin inside `w`. For this, you need a little bit of broadcasting:

```
>>> z = a[...,None]-w[None,None]
tensor([[[ 0.7192,  0.3892,  0.0592, -0.2808],
         [ 0.6264,  0.2964, -0.0336, -0.3736],
         [ 0.5180,  0.1880, -0.1420, -0.4820],
         [ 0.8836,  0.5536,  0.2236, -0.1164]],

        [[ 0.1067, -0.2233, -0.5533, -0.8933],
         [ 0.1216, -0.2084, -0.5384, -0.8784],
         [ 0.6250,  0.2950, -0.0350, -0.3750],
         [ 0.7356,  0.4056,  0.0756, -0.2644]]])
```

We have to identify for each point in `a`, at which index (visually represented as columns here) the sign change occurs. We can apply the [`sign`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.sign.html) operator, then compute difference `z[i+1]-z[i]` between columns with [`diff`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.diff.html), retrieve the non zero values with [`nonzero`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nonzero.html), then finally select and reshape the resulting tensor:

```
>>> index = z.sign().diff(dim=-1).nonzero()[:,2].view(2,4)
tensor([[2, 1, 1, 2],
        [0, 0, 1, 2]])
```

To get `amin`, simply index `w` with `index`:

```
>>> w[index]
tensor([[0.6600, 0.3300, 0.3300, 0.6600],
        [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.3300, 0.6600]])
```

And to get `amax`, we can offset the indices to jump to the upper bound:

```
>>> w[index+1]
tensor([[1.0000, 0.6600, 0.6600, 1.0000],
        [0.3300, 0.3300, 0.6600, 1.0000]])
```